# Is await necessary in async generator functions?

Tags: javascript

MDN has [an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) in which a generator function is marked as `async`, and `yield` is used without `await`.

Why is `await` not necessary in this example?

```js
const myAsyncIterable = {
    async* [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        yield "hello"
        yield "async"
        yield "iteration!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because an function is `async` doesn't mean that `await` is required. I think this example has `async` just to show that you could easily insert an `await`ed Promise into it.

Something with a `Symbol.asyncIterator` can be iterated over asynchronously *if needed*, but it doesn't *have* to have any asynchronous operations. You could even replace the async function with a standard generator function, on the `Symbol.asyncIterator` property, and still have things work just fine:

```js
const myAsyncIterable = {
    *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        yield "hello"
        yield "async"
        yield "iteration!"
    }
};

(async () => {
  for await (const item of myAsyncIterable) {
    console.log(item);
  }
})();
```

Looking at the specification, after the iterator is retrieved from the object, it doesn't matter whether the iterator is sync or async. An async generator function will result in an async iterator; a sync generator function will result in a sync iterator. See the final step 7 of the spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) - [GetIterator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getiterator) will be invoked, and whatever object that's on `Symbol.asyncIterator` will be returned, if it exists, without regard to whether it's actually async or not.

With the iterator, when iterated over with `for await`, [each value returned by the iterator will be `await`ed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset):

> b. If iteratorKind is async, then set nextResult to ? `Await(nextResult)`.

And it's perfectly fine to `await` something that isn't a Promise, it's just odd:

```js
(async () => {
  const item = await 'foo';
  console.log(item);
})();
```

`await` will unwrap a Promise if the expression to its right is a Promise, and will leave it unchanged otherwise.

Comment: Use `yield await`? You could, but it would be better to simply `yield` the Promise, since it'll be unwrapped by something equivalent to an `await` when used by the `for-await` construct. You might `await` if you wanted to do something with an `await`ed value *other than* immediately yielding it.